# Can $f(x,y) = |x|^y$ be be made continuous?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Can  $f(x,y) =  |x|^y$  be appropriately defined at (0,0) in order to be continous there .

if we approach from path y=mx then f(x) becomes |x|^mx with x approaches to 0 .then by taking logs and we get infinity by infinity form . on solving with regular l'hop method ans comes cout to be e^-mx .which is dependent to m . am i right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what values $x$ and $y$ are otherwise allowed to take, but if they can both be any real number (or any complex number) the answer is no.

$f(0,y)\rightarrow 0$ as $y\rightarrow 0$ (coming from the positive real direction), but $f(x,0)\rightarrow 1$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ (also coming from the positive real direction). Since $f(0,0)$ can't be both $0$ and $1$, it can't be made continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Do you mean $f(0,y)\to 0$ instead of $f(x,1)\to 0?$

Comment: Did you mean for your second limit to write $f(x, x) \rightarrow 1$?

Comment: @mfl I didn't mean to write that, but I should have done since you're right and I'm wrong. I've edited to use your suggestion; I'm sorry that I'm getting points for this rather than you.

Comment: Your idea was correct. Typos are not important, if the idea drives to solution. The points you are obtaining are a just reward.

Comment: @mfl (I'm pinging mfl because this way both mfl and Oscar will be pinged) I don't get it, $f$ isn't even defined on the path $t\mapsto (0,t)$

Comment: @GitGud It is defined for $t>0.$

Comment: @mfl $f(x,y)=e^{y\log(|x|)}$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Git: $0^t=0$ unambigiously (and uncontroversially) when $t>0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Any definition of $a^b$ in the context of real numbers I see (I'm looking at two of them), requires $a>0$.

Comment: @GitGud: So you contend, for example, that the function $x\mapsto x^\pi$ needs to be considered undefined at $x=0$? I think that is a somewhat nonstandard position.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, I do. I always thought my position was standard, to be honest. Anyway, if it is defined at $0$, then I agree with the answer. Whether it is or is not, is a different matter. Thank you.