# limit of $ x^{y} $ in several variables

Tags: limits

What is the limit

$ x^{y} =A $ when both variables tend to $0$??

I gues that $ A=1$ if we make a change to polar coordinates

$ y =r\sin(u) $ and $ x=r\cos(u) $

then I get something like $ e^{rf(u)} $ and in the limit $ r\to 0 $ this is equal to $1$.

Also if possible could anyone make a plot of the function $ y\log(x) $ near the origin $ (0,0) $ what else can be done ?

Comment: similar q      http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999786/can-fx-y-xy-be-be-made-continuous

Answer (score 4):

You actually showed that for every sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ *with constant ratio* $x_n/y_n$, the limit is $1$. However, if we set $x_n=1/n^n$ and $y_n=1/n$ we get $$x_n^{y_n}=\frac{1}{n}\to0,$$ and that means the limit does not exist.

Comment: Another example would be $x_n = e^{-n}$ and $y_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Then $x_n^{y_n} = e^{-1}$ for all $n$. Following this we can actually see that for every $r > 0$ there are $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $x_n \to 0$ and $y_n \to 0$ and $x_n^{y_n} \to r$.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on *how* they approach $(0,0)$. For example, along a straight line (i.e. $u$ fixed in polar coordinates), we have

- for $u=0$: $\lim_{r\to 0^+}(r\cos u)^{r\sin u}=\lim_{r\to 0^+}r^0=\lim_{r\to 0}1=1$
- for $u=\frac\pi 2$: $\lim_{r\to 0^+}(r\cos u)^{r\sin u}=\lim_{r\to 0^+}0^r=\lim_{r\to 0}0=0$

Consequently, the general limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x^y$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The story is old hat! See :

"Zero to the power of zero" in : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero

"Zero to the zero-th power" in :
https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zero-th-Power